# How to interpret output of query store in sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-store, azure-sql-managed-instance

I ran the following query shown in the image below. I understand the left pane of the query store below that says query (with id 1962) took about 151000 ms to run.

**Question**: But I don't understand the second pane (plan summary of the same query) of the image below:

1. What are numbers 173490, 173495,173500,... on the vertical axis there
2. What does the blue dot indicate there, and what the small square next to it is about?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't immediate obvious how to interpret Query Store (QS) data in general, and here we also have a GUI on top of that data.

First: QS doesn't store each single execution of a query (or, to be more precise: each single execution of an execution plan). It aggregates the data to a certain time period. The QS configuration option is named `INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES`. The default is 1 hour. I.e., this is the level of granularity you have. Two executions, for instance, in the same time period (one potentially fast and one slow) will be aggregated and represented together.

Regarding the GUI, the screen that you posted:

We need to take into account how many times the query has been executed. The left side is a total of I/O operations for the time period that you are displaying. You select that time period in upper right, "Configure". The default is the last hour.

To the right you have representations of the time aggregates (`INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES`) within that time period you configured above.

[image]

I have configured the GUI to show the last 15 minutes.

I have configured QS with an aggregation interval (`INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES`) of 1 minute (nice for tests like this, but not for production).
We are looking at the query which is lighter green in the left diagram, query with ID 263. (The query happens to have two execution plans, but that is beside the point.)

The bar to the left is the *summary for the time period that I have selected in the GUI*, 15 minutes in my case. You can see in the tool-tip that the query has been executed 10 times in this time period. The tool tip in the picture came from hoovering over the bar in the left diagram.

To the *right*, you have slices for the displayed time period. How many you have depends on your selected aggregation interval (`INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES`). In my case I have one minute, so I have one slice per minute. The scale here is the *aggregates within this time period*. Furthermore, to the right, we also see the individual execution plans separate from each other; plan A, plan B, etc).

To summarize, for the picture I posted:

To the left we can see that for the 10 executions I did in last 15 minutes, the sum of duration is about 300 ms.

In the right diagram, for instance the right-most "dot", represents one aggregate period and the sum duration for the execution over that time period.

[image]

Here you can see that for this aggregation period we executed the query 4 times (for the dot that I hoover over), with a sum duration of 54 ms.

Note that you decide what metric to work with (Duration in our case) and what statistic to show (Total in our case, I refer to it as "sum" in the text above).